# Determine if a word is an isogram, array subscription error

Tags: c

I wrote a function that determines if a word is an isogram or not. I am close to the end but I have got few errors which I am not able to understand, because one of my compiler understands it but another doesn't.

The errors are:

```
solution.c:23:9: warning: array subscript is of type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]
        isogram[c]=isogram[c]+1;
               ^~
solution.c:23:20: warning: array subscript is of type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]
        isogram[c]=isogram[c]+1;
                      ^~
2 warnings generated.
```

And the code:

```
bool IsIsogram(char *str)
{
  int isogram[256];
  int i,len_str,cpt,occs;
  char c;

  for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      len_str=i;
  }

  for (i=0; i<=256;i++){isogram[i]=0;}
  for(i=0; i <= len_str; i++){
      c = str[i];
      c = tolower(c);
      str[i] = c;
  }
 cpt=0;
 for (i = 0; i < len_str; i++) {
    c = str[i];
    isogram[c]=isogram[c]+1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  occs = isogram[i];
  if (occs > 0) {
    cpt++;
  }
  }
  if (cpt==len_str) {
      return true;
  }
  else{
  return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Type `char` is a bad decision to subscript an array. It can be signed or unsigned.

Comment: @Klasnik Alaks If you have an array declared like int isogram[256]; then the valid range of indices is 0-255

Comment: `for (i=0; i<=256;i++){isogram[i]=0;}`will go out of bounds.

Comment: Excellent job checking and resolving each warning. Generally array indexes are expected to be `int`. While if your array has less than 128 elements, a `char` will cover all elements. The warning is generated because [C11 Standard - 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2) specifies `"...E1[E2] ... if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer..."` So while not mandating an integer, the standard is written in terms of an integer. The warning is due to concerns with the range of `char`.

Answer (score 2):

Type char is a bad decision to subscript an array. It can be signed or unsigned. You can fix the warning using `unsigned char`. You should also change the range of your for loop.

```
bool IsIsogram(char *str)
{
  int isogram[256];
  int i,len_str,cpt,occs;
  unsigned char c;

  for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      len_str=i;
  }

  for (i=0; i<256;i++){isogram[i]=0;} // i <=256 goes out of bounds
  for(i=0; i <= len_str; i++){
      c = str[i];
      c = tolower(c);
      str[i] = c;
  }
 cpt=0;
 for (i = 0; i < len_str; i++) {
    c = str[i];
    isogram[c]=isogram[c]+1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  occs = isogram[i];
  if (occs > 0) {
    cpt++;
  }
  }
  if (cpt==len_str) {
      return true;
  }
  else{
  return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning is because `char` is usually a bad idea to use as subscript. If it's signed, the max value is 127.

Solution: Change `char c;` to `unsigned char c;`

Also, change `for (i=0; i<=256;i++)` to `for (i=0; i<256;i++)` or you will go out of bounds. You could do `for (i=0; i<=255;i++)` but it's ideomatic in C to loop over a half open interval.

That fixes the bugs. But also consider declaring loop variables in the for header instead of outside: `for (int i=0; i<256;i++)` but in this case, the easiest thing would be to skip the first loop completely that is only for zeroing the array, and instead initialize the array upon declaration: `int isogram[256] = {0};`

Comment: This only fixes the warning. `c = str[i]` may still result in `c` being negative.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. True. Fixed.